# Regression analysis when the independent variables are part of each other

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multilevel-analysis

I would like to correlate the equipment total number of working hours per day to the total dispatched/shipped qty per day. However, I believe that two products will have more effect than others (more working hours are needed to prepare for shipping). I have three variables that I would like to study their effect on one dependent variable (working hours).

$X_1$: total shipped qty.

$X_2$: shipped qty from product A.

$X_3$: shipped qty from product B.

$X_2$ and $X_3$ are part of $X_1$.

I want to know how much of variation in working hours are explained by $X_1, X_2, X_3$ combined. In some instants, $Y$ is explained by $X_1$ but in other points you may see an extra spike in working hours that can be explained by the increase of shipped qty from product A and/or B without neglecting the effect of $X_1$. Please advise how can I model this in regression model and quantify how much of variation is explained by these factors ($R^2$ maybe) .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of the description, shipped quantities are likely to be additive. So if X4 was the quantitiy of everything but A and B, you could set up the equation

$X_1 = X_2 + X_3 + X_4$

This easily turns into

$X_4 = X_1 - X_2 - X_3$

We have all the values given on the right, so we can compute it and regress

$y \leftarrow \beta_0 +\beta_1\cdot X_2 + \beta_2\cdot X_3 + \beta_3\cdot (X_1-X_2-X_3)$

This can be done with any linear regression function that will provide the $R^2$ you seek. $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ will be workinghours per quantitiy shipped for A and B, $\beta_3$ will be working hours per quantitiy shipped for everything else and $\beta_0$ will be set-up time / start-up time independend on quantity.